# How can I prevent Windows from spinning up all drives when I delete something? 

Tags: windows, recycle-bin, spinup

When I delete something Windows spin up all sleeping hard drives. Even those totally unaffected by the procedure.

Is there a way of preventing this, or it's just a Windows bug?

(Using Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit - Recycle bin turned on on all drives)

Comment: I think its just a Windows bug.

Comment: Not bug, feature*

Comment: Is Windows Search on? You might want to try turning it off.

Answer (score 2):

If you empty the Recycle Bin you cannot prevent that. The Recycle Bin includes the files and directories from all drives, thus Explorer needs to check which files to delete, thus causing the drives to spin up.